# Change Text or Functionality of Buttons in IMG.LY Editor in Angular environment

Tags: angular, imglykit

Trying to customize the export button and close button on the imgly photoeditor. Using version 5.17.2 currently of the photoeditorsdk. I need to be able to change the text of the export button to say 'Upload' and would like to have the close button always enabled. I haven't been able to accomplish either goal.

According to this link: https://support.img.ly/hc/en-us/articles/7772957651729-Can-I-customize-the-export-button-
I can only customize buttons in Android or iOS app environment. However in their docs (https://img.ly/docs/pesdk/web/customization/icons/) about changing icons they mention changing label or disabled property of buttons. I tried using their code but I get a ton of errors and their code appears to be react-native (best guess at least) so I don't know how this is going to work. Then I tried going into the node modules to find the definition for their buttons so I could build from there but when I try to access the properties it says it doesn't exist on CustomButton type. Kind of at a loss on how this is actually supposed to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the easiest way to change the text of the export button would be through the [localization](https://img.ly/docs/pesdk/web/customization/localization/#changing-labels-for-existing-languages) object:

```
  this.editor = await PhotoEditorSDKUI.init({
  license,
  container: this.container ? this.container.nativeElement : '',
  image: this.src,
  assetBaseUrl:
    'https://cdn.img.ly/packages/imgly/photoeditorsdk/5.17.3/assets',
  custom: {
    languages: {
      en: {
        mainCanvasActions: {
          buttonExport: 'Upload',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

The [createElement API](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/createElement) of React allows you to create a custom close button:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Component,
  AfterViewInit,
  ViewChild,
  Input,
  ElementRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  PhotoEditorSDKUI,
  EditorApi,
  OutlinedSecondaryButton,
  CustomButtonProps,
} from 'photoeditorsdk/no-polyfills';

const license = '';

const CloseButton = (props: CustomButtonProps) =>
  React.createElement(OutlinedSecondaryButton, {
    ...props,
    isDisabled: false,
  });

@Component({
  selector: 'app-photo-editor',
  templateUrl: './photo-editor.component.html',
})
export class PhotoEditorComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input()
  public src = '';

  @ViewChild('editor', { static: false })
  private container: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement> | null = null;

  public editor: EditorApi | null = null;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.initEditor();
  }

  async initEditor() {
    try {
      if (this.editor) {
        this.editor.dispose();
      }

      this.editor = await PhotoEditorSDKUI.init({
        license,
        container: this.container ? this.container.nativeElement : '',
        image: this.src,
        assetBaseUrl:
          'https://cdn.img.ly/packages/imgly/photoeditorsdk/5.17.3/assets',
        custom: {
          components: {
            buttons: { mainCanvasActionClose: CloseButton },
          },
        },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```